# R-Studio Mosaicplot and Conditional Formatting

Tags: r, plot, formatting, conditional-statements, mosaic

I have the table below:

```
 Server Package       Version        Status
1  Serv1   Pack1          Ver1    Up To Date
2  Serv1   Pack2          Ver1      Outdated
3  Serv2   Pack1 Not Installed Not Installed
4  Serv2   Pack2          Ver2    Up To Date
5  Serv3   Pack1          Ver1    Up To Date
6  Serv3   Pack2 Not Installed Not Installed
```

I want to create a mosaic graph to show server versus package, with the resulting tiles colored to represent their status.

I am using:

```
mosaicplot(mini_conda$Server~mini_conda$Package, 
xlab = "Server", 
ylab = "Package", 
main = "")
```

The produced plot is almost correct, but I can't figure out how to correctly color the tiles.

Thanks,

UPDATE:
data in dput()

```
> (dput(mini_conda))
structure(list(Server = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Serv1", 
"Serv2", "Serv3"), class = "factor"), Package = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Pack1", "Pack2"), class = "factor"), 
    Version = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Not Installed", 
    "Ver1", "Ver2"), class = "factor"), Status = structure(c(3L, 
    2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("Not Installed", "Outdated", 
    "Up To Date"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Server", "Package", 
"Version", "Status"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
  Server Package       Version        Status
1  Serv1   Pack1          Ver1    Up To Date
2  Serv1   Pack2          Ver1      Outdated
3  Serv2   Pack1 Not Installed Not Installed
4  Serv2   Pack2          Ver2    Up To Date
5  Serv3   Pack1          Ver1    Up To Date
6  Serv3   Pack2 Not Installed Not Installed
```

Comment: can you provide you data in dput-format? (dput(mini_conda))?

Comment: See update to original question.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is with the `vcd` package:

```
# install.packages("vcd")
library(vcd)
mosaic(~ Server + Package + Status, data = mini_conda,
       highlighting = "Status", direction = c("v", "h", "h"),
       highlighting_fill = c("lightblue", "pink", "lightgreen"))
```

[image: mosaic]

Depending on the data, you may want to use `ggplot2`:

```
# install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mini_conda, aes(x = Server, y = Package, fill = Status)) +
  geom_tile()
```

[image: ggplot]

Answer (score 0):

A ggplot approach:

```
p1 <- ggplot(mini_conda, aes(x = "", y = Package)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill=Status)) +
  facet_grid(.~Server) +
  coord_fixed() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Not Installed"="red",
                      "Outdated"="orange",
                      "Up To Date" = "green")) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(
    axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
    strip.background = element_blank()
  ) + labs(
    x="", y=""
  )
```

[image]